# display image after url redirection in sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to insert an Image in Google Sheet the URL, https://storage.cloud.google.com/test/7691/000112/002.png,  using

`=Image("https://storage.cloud.google.com/test/7691/000112/002.png")`

but it doesn't work ,however,when I open it in browser it is redirected to a very long URL, is there a way to edit the =Image(..) so it actually puts in the image URL after redirection

when I use `=Image('url_after_redirection')` it works fine

Comment: I think that in this case, how about replacing the URL to the redirected URL using OnEdit event trigger? But in this case, it is required to know whether the redirected URL is the permanent URL. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike the url after redirection is changed everytime I visit it, can you explain more on "OnEdit"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, that the image of redirected URL might not be the permanent. So in this case, when the expiration time of URL is over, the image might be removed. I'm worry about this. By the way, about the trigger, you can see the official document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: @Tanaike even if I use an old long url it still opens, so you might consider as permanent. How can I use it

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the URL can be used as the permanent URL, you can achieve this by creating a script with Google Apps Script. The OnEdit event trigger is used for executing the script. In your case, the installable trigger might be required to be used.

Comment: @Tanaike I found a better way, by simply making the url public-hence google stops redirecting

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plenty of search on this subject, I found the simplest solution is to use googleapistorage link and making the image public.

Here's the Cloud storage [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) to make objects like images public.